# React - click input in child component from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I click a input (open file dialog) in a child component from the parent component? Here's what I have but I'm not quite sure how to bring it home in the click handler.

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react';
const inputRef = createRef();

// Parent ==============
const Parent = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    // open file dialog in child
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Child />
      <button onClick={handleClick}></button>
    </>
  );
};

// Child ==============
const Child = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" ref={inputRef} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used forwardRef to pass the ref from parent to child.

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react';
const inputRef = createRef();

// Parent ==============
const Parent = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    inputRef.current.click();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Child ref={inputRef}/>
      <button onClick={handleClick}></button>
    </>
  );
};

// Child ==============
const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" ref={ref} />
    </>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `inputRef.current.click();` inside your handleClick method.

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react';
const inputRef = createRef();

// Parent ==============
const Parent = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    inputRef.current.click();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Child />
      <button onClick={handleClick}></button>
    </>
  );
};

// Child ==============
const Child = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" ref={inputRef} />
    </>
  );
};
```